# VBA Sub seems to be skipping over connection declarations

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Edit: 
It turns out that the cause is me using a textbox instead of a listbox. The code was meant for filling a listbox with the results of a recordset. I didn't adapt it to filling a textbox with one single result. If anyone else is experiencing anything similar I hope this helps you out! Thanks for taking a look

I have several SQL queries that I run in a VBA project in excel.They are run off of button clicks.  I declare all the connection variables and so on in each Sub then close them when it's done running. Most of them are just copy and paste of the following with the SQL Query variables changed:

```
Public Sub AgentsReporting()
Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Server_Name = "SDL02-VM25"
Database_Name = "PIA"
SQLStr = "select distinct[Agent Name] from dbo.[Master Staffing List] Where [Team] ='" & Reporting.ChooseTeam.Value & "'"
Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & vbNullString
rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
With Reporting.ChooseAgent
.Clear
Do
.AddItem rs![Agent Name]
rs.MoveNext
Loop Until rs.EOF
End With
rs.Close
Cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set Cn = Nothing
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

So far all of them work except for the one below. When I step through it it seems to skip over all the declarations and gives me a "Method or Data Member not found" error and highlights the ".clear" line.

```
Sub GetLateLessThan()
Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Server_Name = "SDL02-VM25"
Database_Name = "PIA"
SQLStr = "select [Weekday Schedule] from dbo.[Master Staffing List] Where [Agent Name] ='" & Reporting.AgentName.Value & "'"
Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & vbNullString
rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
With Reporting.LateLessThan
    .Clear
    Do
    .AddItem rs![Weekday Schedule]
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop Until rs.EOF
End With
rs.Close
Cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set Cn = Nothing
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

I cannot figure out why it's not working. It looks like it should be working fine, I've double checked the with statement, double checked the names of the variables. Does anyone have any idea as to why this particular sub is failing when the other ones seem to work fine?

Comment: Shot in the dark - are you missing a library reference?

Comment: Not that I can see. Again, all the other ones work fine. About 7 other subs in total, all with the same declarations. All work fine.

Comment: Where is this subroutine located, in the same module as the others? What about changing it from a `Sub` to a `Public Sub`? It looks like `.LateLessThan` is something created elsewhere.

Comment: I have a module that contains all the SQL queries as individual subs. They are called on button click. I tried adding Public to it but no joy.  LateLessThan is a text box on the userform Reporting.

Comment: that's the issue; not properly referring to `Reporting.LateLessThan`.  (re: your other comment: When stepping through code, VBA will never stop on variable declaration.)

Comment: I know you can't see all the forms but do you have any tips as far as properly referring to it? I'm not sure how I'm not doing it correctly.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting results? After `rs.Open...` throw in a `If not rs.BOF And not rs.EOF` - that will ensure you're only trying to access the contents of the recordset _if_ there are records in it.

Comment: It's pulling in results. I've even just replaced " & Reporting.AgentName.Value & "   with an actual name I know will pull in results and it still skips it over.

Comment: So, I just realized that the cause is me using a textbox instead of a listbox. The code was meant for filling a listbox with the results of a recordset. I didn't adapt it to filling a textbox with one single result. If anyone else is experiencing anything similar I hope this helps you out! Thanks for taking a look.